# How can I add image in UITableView section header using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, header, uiimageview

I have a 4 header. I want to add a image next to the header.

These are my header array;

```
let sections: [String] = ["Cleaning","Computer Repair", "Electircity", "Painting", "Plumbing"]
```

How can I add image in UITableView section header using swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to confirm some **UITableViewDataSource** and **UITableViewDelegate** methods.

To declare number of sections call `func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int` method

To show image in Section Header call `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?` method

If you want to set the height of the section header call `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat` method.

In `viewForHeaderInSection` method you can design your header. And don't forget to set **AutoLayoutConstraint**

You can create an array of UIImage to show image in section header like this

```
let sectionImages: [UIImage] = [picutre1, picture2, picture3, picture4]
```

Here is the full code.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = sectionImages[section]
    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = .white
    headerView.addSubview(imageView)

    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true   
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true

    return headerView
}
```

Comment: Well, if I create an array like this, """ sectionImages: [[UIImages]] = [[picture1],[picture2],[picture3],[picture4],[picture5]]

Comment: How can I add header this array

Comment: Is ```sectionImages``` is an array of UIImage?

Comment: Array should be like this ```sectionImages: [UIImage] = [picture1, picture2, picture3, picture4]```

Comment: I'm sorry I wrote it wrong. My question is how can I use this sectionImages for header image